# how to read json file and assign the value to variable in shell

Tags: json, shell, parsing, unix

I have following *.json file in the jenkins $workspace location.

I'm changing the directory to the *.json directory and tried to read value by using the below commands and assign to variable

**Script:**

```
for file in test*.json; do

echo '$file' #It prints the file name like test1342124.json

value=$(cat '$file')

echo $value

done
```

**Output:**

```
test1342124.json
echo $value
```

The echo $value prints as $value in output. I just want it to store the json file data and I want to parse it and use it for other API service request.

Is this can be done? Is it possible to check JSON.parse(String) after it assigned to $value?

Comment: Your script won't produce the output you show due to single quoted variable expansions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Double quotes `"$file"` are required, single quotes will not parse the `$` meta character correctly.

```
   for file in test*.json; do
    echo "$file"   #It prints the file name like test1342124.json
    value=$(cat "$file")
    echo $value
    done
```

Answer (score 0):

You should do value=`cat yourfile` (symbol left from Digit 1 on keyboard)